# How to trade on whether one asset will be higher than another?

Tags: derivatives

I was wondering if there is any way to trade on whether or not one asset would earn a higher return than another in some predetermined time period. It would be sort of like gambling on horses except for shares in companies. For example, I could make a trade today that in one months time, apple's share will have yielded a greater return than google's shares. Then, if this happens, the person I closed the deal with pays me a premium, if not, I pay them. That way, I do not necessarily have to determine whether or not the company will go up or down, I just have to determine whether it will outperform another company (even for negative returns).

Are there any financial instruments that would let you speculate in this way? I was thinking that maybe some combinations of options would be able to do it, but I haven't yet figured out how. Please let me know if you have any ideas how to trade in this way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you simply want to do a pair trade (i.e. long one stock and short the other). I doubt this is more easily done via single stock futures (illiquid) and standard implementation would be cash equity L/S. You could also trade an outperformance option on the two stocks.

Comment: If you are not borrowing in large amounts, borrowing can be costly and supply can turn out to be problematic at times depending on the stock if you go the cash route. Speculating for relatively small amounts is easier with single stock futures. In addition, the OP is about any two assets and you may have even more trouble in finding assets to borrow in certain asset classes.

Comment: Hi Alper - OP mentions Apple and Google. I don't see any volume in EUREX single stock futures for Alphabet (Dec21 contract). If liquidity is concentrated in a different venue, please let me know as I'm always happy to learn. Thanks!

Comment: If you kindly read the OP again, it appears to be written regarding any two assets and these two are given as examples only. As for your other question, not sure about the US, but single stock futures are quite popular in many other countries. See this article for a list: https://www.marketswiki.com/wiki/Single_stock_futures

Answer (score 0):

You can speculate on one stock outperforming another over the next few months using single stock futures. You would buy the futures of the stock you think that will outperform and sell the futures of the one that you think will underperform. Another way to do it is to buy the stock to outperform and borrow and sell the one to underperform but it is usually easier and less costly to do it via single stock futures, especially if you are dealing with relatively large volumes. This [Investopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/06/singlestockfutures.asp) tells more about single stock futures.

You can speculate on the relative performance of pretty much any two assets that have future markets using the same method with single stock futures.